# How to get the width of a GridView Column in rowbound event?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview

I have a column named "Weightage"  in GridView. I have a textbox outside the gridview called "Total" I want to align this textbox right below the column Weightage.

```
 </asp:GridView>
   <div>
           <span id="q1totalweightage" runat="server">Total<asp:TextBox ID="txtq1totalweightage" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox></span>
   </div>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void grvGoals_RowDataBound1(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Row.RowType)
    {
      case DataControlRowType.DataRow:
      q1totalweightage.Attributes.Add("style", "margin-left: " +     e.Row.Cells[0].Width + "px;");
 break;
     }
```

**NOTE:** Assume that I can not place this total textbox within footer for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You *cannot* get the computed width of the `GridView` column in server side. For that you have to use `JavaScript`.

For that you have to give a classname to your column like this

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contact Name">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="ContactName" runat="server"  
            CssClass="my-column"
            Text='<%# Eval("ContactName") %>'>
        </asp:Label>                
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Also no need to use `runat="server"` for the span.

```
<span id="q1totalweightage">Total
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtq1totalweightage" runat="server" >
    </asp:TextBox>
</span>
```

Vanilla JavaScript

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    var column = document.getElementsByClassName("my-column")[0].parentNode;
    var row = column.parentNode;
    var newMargin = row.clientWidth - column.clientWidth;
    document.getElementById("q1totalweightage").style.marginLeft = newMargin + "px";
});
```

Or jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var column = $(".my-column:first").closest("td");
    var row = column.closest("tr");
    //var newMargin = row.width() - column.width();
    var newMargin = row.outerWidth() - column.outerWidth();
    $("#q1totalweightage").css("margin-left", newMargin + "px");
});
```

P.S: This code assumes that the column **Contact Name** is the *last* column of the table.